# get MongoDatabase with spring data mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to tail the mongo oplog collection indefinitely. The code that I currently use is as below.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(<host>,<27017>);

MongoCollection oplogColl =
                   mongoClient
                           .getDatabase("local")
                           .getCollection("oplog.rs");

MongoCursor oplogCursor =
                   oplogColl
                           .find(new Document("ts", filter))
                           .cursorType(CursorType.TailableAwait)
                           .noCursorTimeout(true)
                           .sort(new Document("$natural", 1))
                           .iterator();
```

I am trying to get the same implementation using spring-data where the mongo uri will be specified in the properties file. Hence I need to access MongoDatabase or MongoClient.

Tried using MongodbFactory class in spring, but it returns a instance of type DB, which is a old mongo implementation to access mongo.

How can I get to use MongoDatabase/MongoCollection/MongoClient using spring data.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: Abhijit Sarkar. I have asked a question here only after searching for it. If you feel that its so straightforward to get this answer in google then why don't you provide the answer here.

Comment: Just did, and it took me less than 10 min. The reason I didn't do it before is because you didn't show any effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

`MongoClient` extends `Mongo`, so

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   public @Bean Mongo mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
       return new Mongo("localhost");
   }
}
```

If you don't want to code to Mongo classes directly

```
/*
* Factory bean that creates the com.mongodb.Mongo instance
*/
@Bean
public MongoClientFactoryBean mongo() {
    MongoClientFactoryBean mongo = new MongoClientFactoryBean();
    mongo.setHost("localhost");
    return mongo;
}
```

**Edit**:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   public @Bean MongoClient mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
       return new MongoClient("localhost");
   }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
@Autowired
private Mongo mongo;

MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(mongo, "databaseName");
```

**Edit**:

```
@Autowired
private MongoClient mongoClient;

MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "databaseName");
```

Comment: Usage of com.mongodb.Mongo class is not encouraged with the latest mongo driver. That is the whole point of my question. Spring-data-mongodb provides MongoDbFactory which in turn provides com.mongodb.DB. And your answer uses com.mongodb.Mongo. All these classes(as well as BasicDBObject etc) are normally not used with the latest drivers. I am trying to find a way where the newer classes like MongoDatabase/ MongoCollection/ MongoClient can be used. 1) You need to understand what is being asked before jumping to conclusions. 2) You need to update yourself on mongo java driver.

Comment: @samo You want to use `MongoClient`, but that extends `Mongo` that you claim to be not recommended? You can return an instance of `MongoClient` from where `Mongo` is returned if you're so inclined. 1) Reading comprehension problem? 2) You need to update yourself on inheritance 101.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-mongoclient.. Read the lines, "That class, Mongo, will maintain the old default, and become deprecated" and "The old class will remain for quite a while (but not forever), so that we won’t break old code right now".

Comment: @samo Since you are apparently not able to understand simple instructions, see my edit.